# How to do order by child class property for a list of parent class?

Tags: c#, linq

Here parent class has child class in child class we have name how to make the list of parent as orderby using name property of child class. I used pq.OrderBy(z => z.Class1.Name != null).ToList(); but the list is not ordered as expected.

```
 class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                List<Parent> pq = new List<Parent>() {

                    new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="d" } },
                    new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="s" } },
                    new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="y" } },
                    new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="r" } },
                    new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="b" } },
                    new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="a" } }
                };

                var assa = pq.OrderBy(z => z.Class1.Name != null).ToList();
            }
        }

        public class Parent
        {
            public Child Class1 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Child
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a pretty simple use of `OrderBy` so it would be useful to know what you've tried and where you got problems (compile issues, runtime exceptions, not ordering correctly, etc.).

Comment: `pq.OrderBy(z => z.Class1.Name)` ?

Comment: Sorry if question is silly i am new to LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want an ordered List you can use this:

```
var assa = pq.OrderBy(p => p.Class1.Name).ToList();
```

If it is possible that `Class1` property is null use this:

```
var assa = pq.Where(p => p.Class1 != null).OrderBy(p => p.Class1.Name).ToList();
```

If you want to have those objects where `Class1` is null at the end of the resulting `List`:

```
var assa = pq.Where(p => p.Class1 != null).OrderBy(p => p.Class1.Name).ToList();
assa.AddRange(pq.Where(p => p.Class1 == null));
```

Comment: You're welcome. please mark as correct answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

use simply the property `Name` as the parameter for the call of the `OrderBy` function and you get your desired result:

```
var assa = pq.OrderBy(z => z.Class1.Name).ToList();
```

the problem in your code is that you give a boolean criterion which is used to determine the ordering. Since all elements in your list checked against this criterion will return true -> the order remains the same. You can test it by setting the Name of the last item to `null`.

```
new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="d" } },
new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="s" } },
new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="y" } },
new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="r" } },
new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name="b" } },
new Parent () { Class1=new Child () { Name=null } }
```

in this case your original query will result in an ordering of the last item as the first one

```
var assa = pq.OrderBy(z => z.Class1.Name != null).ToList();
```

Comment: @BhuvaneshNarayanasamy how do you test it? `pq` will still have the same order. the returned list `assa` will have the ordered elements

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your ordering function:

```
var assa = pq.OrderBy(z => z.Class1.Name != null).ToList();
```

If you notice, you are returning a boolean value from the function:

```
z => z.Class1.Name != null
```

What you want is to return the value of the Name property:

```
z => z.Class1.Name
```

Change it to this:

```
var assa = pq.OrderBy(z => z.Class1.Name).ToList();
```